# How to auto-open photo in Colorbox only when it's specified in URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, colorbox

This code gives each Colorbox image an URL (domain.com/#image). This can then be copied and pasted by user to open the wanted photo automatically when entering the site with that URL.

Everything works as intended but somehow it also auto-opens the first image on the site even when there is no #image at the end of the URL. How should I change this code that it will only auto-open the image when there is #image in the URL?

Thanks!

Code:

```
jQuery(function (){
            var id, group;

            group = jQuery("a[rel='lightbox[63]']").colorbox({onComplete:function(){
                    // Get the image URL
                    with_ext = (this.pathname.match(/\/([^\/?#]+)$/i) || [,''])[1];
                    // Get the image url without the extension
                    without_ext =  with_ext.substring(0, with_ext.lastIndexOf("."));
                    // Redirect
                    window.location.hash = without_ext;
            }, onClosed: function(){
                    location.hash = '';
            }});

            id = location.hash.replace(/^\#/, '')+".jpg";

            group.filter('[href$="'+id+'"]').eq(0).click();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it working. 
If anyone else needs this kind of function here it is:

```
jQuery(function (){
            var id, group;

            group = jQuery("a[rel='lightbox[63]']").colorbox({onComplete:function(){
                    // Get the image URL
                    with_ext = (this.pathname.match(/\/([^\/?#]+)$/i) || [,''])[1];
                    // Get the image url without the extension
                    without_ext =  with_ext.substring(0, with_ext.lastIndexOf("."));
                    // Redirect
                    window.location.hash = without_ext;
            }, onClosed: function(){
                    location.hash = '';
            }});

            if(window.location.hash) {

                    id = location.hash.replace(/^\#/, '')+".jpg";
                    group.filter('[href$="'+id+'"]').eq(0).click();

            } else {
                    return;
            }


    });
```